# Inside mybatis-config.xml, is possible to read properties from pom.xml in a Maven project?

Tags: maven, jdbc, mybatis

I'm developing a sample multi-module maven project that uses MyBatis. The only dependencies I have are my own modules and mybatis it self.

On my persistence layer, I have created the following on `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>

    <!-- JDBC -->
        <jdbc.url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/kpi?autoReconnect=true</jdbc.url>
        <jdbc.driverClassName>org.postgresql.Driver</jdbc.driverClassName>
        <jdbc.username>postgres</jdbc.username>
        <jdbc.password>postgres</jdbc.password>
        <jdbc.initConnections>15</jdbc.initConnections>
        <jdbc.maxActive>40</jdbc.maxActive>
        <jdbc.maxIdle>5</jdbc.maxIdle>

</properties>
```

Then, in `mybatis-config.xml` inside `src/main/resources`, I did the following:

```
<environments default='development'>
    <environment id='development'>
        <transactionManager type='JDBC'/>
        <dataSource type='POOLED'>  
            <property name='driver' value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
            <property name='url' value="${jdbc.url}"/>
            <property name='username' value="${jdbc.username}"/>
            <property name='password' value="${jdbc.password}"/>
        </dataSource>
    </environment>
```

After all, when I try to run the application I get the following error:

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Error setting driver on  UnpooledDataSource. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: ${jdbc.driverClassName}
```

But, when I change the above code, explicitly typing the information from jdbc, it works:

```
 <environments default='development'>
    <environment id='development'>
        <transactionManager type='JDBC'/>
        <dataSource type='POOLED'>  
            <property name='driver' value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name='url' value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/kpi?autoReconnect=true"/>
            <property name='username' value="postgres"/>
            <property name='password' value="postgres"/>
        </dataSource>
    </environment>
</environments>
```

So, is that possible to make it works using the information I put inside my `pom.xml`? I tried using the `<properties resource='pom.xml'/>` tag but with no success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, technically you cannot read properties in POM when MyBatis run, because POM is something used in compilation, and when MyBatis run, it is already runtime which has already passed the compilation.  Therefore it is simply not reasonable to read data from POM (unless your MyBatis config is part of the automated testing in your build process, but it seems not in your case)

You can achieve similar effect by using Maven's resource filtering mechanism, for which placeholders in your `mybatis-config.xml` is replaced with properties defined in Maven during build process.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

You may have some settings in your POM which stop filtering on your resources directory which caused your problem.  Please check if the properties are properly replaced in your JAR/WAR after you have built your application.

However, personally I will not suggest you doing so.  Such kind of properties are environment specific and shouldn't be "hardcoded" in your result artifact.  You should consider updating your design, so that you can provide a config file or provide command line argument when running your application, so that you do not need to build the app again just to cope with another environment.

Comment: Hello @Adrian Shum! I'll accept your suggestion, I no longer need `pom.xml` for this. I'm going to provide a config file for database configuration. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

At which maven task will you like pom.xml to be read?

At the point where you execute mvn compile? mvn package? or otherwise?

Comment: Hello @mallim! I already solved the problem updating my design. `pom.xml` is no longer needed for this =) Thanks anyway.